# Where can I permanently modify $Path?

Tags: system-variables

I've quite forgotten: what file does one modify in order to add directories to `$Path` globally? Specifically, I want to include `$UserBaseDirectory/ExtraPackges`.

Or does one do it by means of modifying some setting in the OptionInspector (for Global Preferences) and, if so, which setting? I didn't see a relevant one under `Global Options>File Locations`.

Comment: Szabolcs suggestion is not working for me. Anytime I quit Mathematica everything i added gets removed. I've tried running as an administrator and that doesn't help.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can add the following line:

```
AppendTo[$Path, FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "ExtraPackges"}]]
```

to the file:

```
FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Kernel", "init.m"}]
```

`init.m` is described [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/file/init.m.html), under "more information".

---

To do this automatically you can run:

```
With[
 {newPath = FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "ExtraPackges"}]},
 PutAppend[
  Unevaluated @ AppendTo[$Path, newPath],
  FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Kernel", "init.m"}]
 ]
]
```

Comment: I suspected the method was to include such an AppendTo, but the issue was which init.m to use. Just to be sure: one uses init.m for Kernel, not for FrontEnd?

And there's no way to do this via OptionInspector?

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to do it from the Options Inspector. I tried the `init.m` in the indicated (`Kernel`) folder and it worked; my mental model of what is going on is: kernel gets started, loads `init.m` and runs it, then starts normal execution. So I just appended the path in there. Basically I think of it as `autoexec.bat` projected roughly 25 years into the future.

Comment: @murray `$Path` is a kernel variable, so this needs to be done for `Kernel/init.m`, exactly as acl said.  I don't think the front end could execute `AppendTo` at all..

Comment: OK, @Szabolics. So the obvious next question is: how could one learn that $Path is a kernel variable, unknown to the front end directly?

Answer (score 2):

You could modify the global options in the options editor (Win.OS**`Ctr + Shif + O`**).

look up the
**EvaluatorStartup**
and put code

```
AppendTo[$Path, FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "ExtraPackges"}]]
```

into the value box and restart the frond end, check the `$Path` again. Note that `;` is necessary to separate different codes.

[image]

Update: for multi-paths, use this code

```
If[!MemberQ[$Path, #] && DirectoryQ@#, 
   AppendTo[$Path, #]] & /@ {FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "ExtraPackges"}],"C:\\temp\\"}
```

if user defined package **MyPackage`** located in **C:\temp\**, then you can find the **init.m**
by

```
FindFile["MyPackage`"]
```

and load it with this code

```
Get[FindFile["MyPackage`"](*,CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"*)(*optional*)]
```